# jQuery applies to element by his old class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html like this

```
<li class="dropable">...</li>
<li class="dropable">...</li>
<li class="dropable">...</li>
```

i change the class name using jQuery

```
jQuery('.dropable').addClass('dropable-mob');
jQuery('.dropable').removeClass('dropable');
```

and i have event listeners for both cases

```
jQuery('.dropable-mob').click(function(){....})
jQuery('.dropable').click(function(){....})
```

The problem is when the class is .dropable-mob and i click the element on the page it calls .dropable click action, but dropable class does not even exists at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind events to a DOM element, they are bound to the element itself, not to its classname: the selector is used only to figure out which element to bind the event to.  Removing the classname does *not* also remove the click event already bound to that DOM element:

```js
$('.foo').on("click", function() {
  console.log("CLICKED");
});

// Remove the class, but the bound event will remain:
$('.foo').removeClass('foo');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="foo">Click me</button>
```

Similarly, adding a classname to an element will not attach events to that element that were bound before the classname was added:

```js
// This won't match anything because when it's called, nothing has .bar:
$('.bar').on("click", function() {
  console.log("CLICKED");
});

// Adding the 'bar' class later will have no effect, because the attempt at event binding already happened:
$('.foo').addClass('bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="foo">Click me</button>
```

If you want to have the event associated with the classname rather than with a specific DOM element, you can use delegated events instead.  Here, the event is bound to a higher-level DOM element, which *at the time of the event trigger* will search within its contents for elements matching the selector:

```js
//This delegated event won't match anything at first:
$('.container').on("click", ".foo", function() {
  console.log("CLICKED");
});

// This will allow the delegated event to fire:
$('#switch').on("click", function() {
  $('.container button').addClass('foo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>

<button id="switch">Add class</button>
```

To clarify the difference:  normal event binding uses the selector *when the event is being bound*, and attaches the event to the specific matched DOM elements.  Delegated event binding binds the event to a parent element,  and uses the selector *when the event is triggered*.

Comment: But why when i commented jQuery('.dropable').click(function(){....}) it stil does not perform jQuery('.dropable-mob').click(function(){....})

Comment: That's again because you changed the classnames *after* binding the events -- when you bound the event, the selector didn't match any DOM elements, so it didn't get bound.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the listeners so that you account for the class changes

```
jQuery('ul')
    .on('click', '.dropable-mob', function(){....})
    .on('click', '.dropable', function(){....})
```

Answer (score -4):

Use the code like below:

```
$("li.dropable").each(function(index) {
  $(this).removeClass('dropable').addClass('dropable-mob');
});
```